# How do I do CRUD updates to SQLite DB from UIPath

Tags: sqlite, uipath

I am unsure which activity I need to run commands to update, delete or add to a datatable in SQLite from UIPath.  Which activities do I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update, insert or delete single records, you will use a Execute non-query activity
It is very similar to the query one except it doesn’t produce a table as output.  The output will be “Affected Records” which is an integer variable.
The query string will be pure SQL